# Not an answer flag declined; however, post deleted

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

My first flag after 877 approved moderator attention flags was declined, and I'm following up to understand what was wrong with my action.

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303476/c-sharp-how-to-fix-error-could-not-find-schema-information-for-the-attribute/18621499#18621499), which includes a *thank you* statement with a loosely coupled statement about visual studio:

> [image: answer]

Even though it was deleted by a moderator, my flag was declined:

> [image: flag]

Conservative with my flags, is this an oversight or was I too hasty in flagging this as not an answer?

Comment: There was also a spam flag on that post, which was completely absurd.

Comment: Oh, right - they get tied together.  Okay, sorry for the noise.

Comment: @animuson: Right? It's always them party poopers.

Comment: That's an excellent flag ratio, by the way! We appreciate quality! and your quantity isn't bad at all either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Moderators don't act on a single flag, they act on *all flags raised for that post* at the same time.  My guess is someone else flagged it as spam/offensive/etc. and it was more important to decline their flag than to accept yours.

That, or the occasional fat finger.  It happens.

Move on, there are more important things than flag weight.  You know the post is NAA, so don't worry about it unless you see several declines.

Comment: Yup, that was what happened here. Good news is that I hear we'll soon be able to selectively accept / decline when there are multiple flags on a post. The developers have been making some nice improvements to the flag system lately.

Comment: @BradLarson what is the ETA? six to eight weeks, or sooner?

Comment: @JanDvorak - The pace things are changing, I wouldn't be surprised if they added it this morning and I just didn't notice yet.

Comment: @BradLarson  wow. Kudos and thanks :-) don't forget to get the respective outstanding feature-request(s) marked as status-completed ;-)

Answer (score 2):

No, your flag was probably correct, but the flag could have been declined either because someone flagged it with the wrong flag (in which case all flags get declined together), or maybe the moderator simply made a mistake when marking the flag.